# replacing a character in a string in a list by index

Tags: string, python-3.x

```
nm,b = input().split()
b = int(b)
n,m = [int(i) for i in nm]
s = '|'
layout = ['-------']
tal = [
['###', '# #', '# #', '# #', '###'],
['  #', '  #', '  #', '  #', '  #'],
['###', '  #', '###', '#  ', '###'],   
['###', '  #', '###', '  #', '###'],
['# #', '# #', '###', '  #', '  #'],
['###', '#  ', '###', '  #', '###'],
['###', '#  ', '###', '# #', '###'],
['###', '  #', '  #', '  #', '  #'],
['###', '# #', '###', '# #', '###'],
['###', '# #', '###', '  #', '###']
]

if b == 1:
    for i in range(5):
        print(tal[n][i][0])
        tal[n][i][0] = ''
        print(tal)
```

So I am trying to edit all of `tal[n][i][0]` (depending on what n the user type) to `' '` (a space). But I got troubles replacing the `#` You can see the code above that I tried.

basically; `tal[n][i][0] = ' '` which is: `tal[0][0][0] = ' '` but that doesnt work. I'll just end up with an TypeError:

I get TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

- **so how should this be done?**

**EXAMPLE**
I want this:

```
tal = [
    ['###', '# #', '# #', '# #', '###'],   <-- this line here
    ['  #', '  #', '  #', '  #', '  #'],
    ['###', '  #', '###', '#  ', '###'],   
    ['###', '  #', '###', '  #', '###'],
    ['# #', '# #', '###', '  #', '  #'],
    ['###', '#  ', '###', '  #', '###'],
    ['###', '#  ', '###', '# #', '###'],
    ['###', '  #', '  #', '  #', '  #'],
    ['###', '# #', '###', '# #', '###'],
    ['###', '# #', '###', '  #', '###']
    ]
```

all the strings in the list at [0] in tal.         look above ^^
In that line. I want at each of the strings in that line, the first index to be replaced by a `' '`. 
So it would look like:

```
 tal = [
        [' ##', '  #', '  #', '  #', ' ##'],   <-- this line here
        ['  #', '  #', '  #', '  #', '  #'],
        ['###', '  #', '###', '#  ', '###'],   
        ['###', '  #', '###', '  #', '###'],
        ['# #', '# #', '###', '  #', '  #'],
        ['###', '#  ', '###', '  #', '###'],
        ['###', '#  ', '###', '# #', '###'],
        ['###', '  #', '  #', '  #', '  #'],
        ['###', '# #', '###', '# #', '###'],
        ['###', '# #', '###', '  #', '###']
        ]
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to replace a str character with another.  Try `tal[n][i][0].replace("#", "")`

Comment: I dont want to replace # with nothing, only if the # is in the index [0] of the each of the strings.

Comment: It's unclear what you want.  Post an example of the output you wish to see.

Comment: @pylang: calling `replace` will not work, since this does not happen inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are **immutable** in Python: you cannot modify them. The only option you have is to construct a new string and replace it.

So instead of:

```
tal[n][i][0] = ' '
```

You have to write:

```
tal[n][i] = ' '+tal[n][i][1:] #instead of tal[n][i][0] = ' '
```

Here you thus replace **the full string** by constructing a new one that begins with a space followed by the remaining characters of the previous string.

In case you want to edit the string on an arbitrary location (say `j`), you can write:

```
tal[n][i] = tal[n][i][:j]+' '+tal[n][i][j+1:] #instead of tal[n][i][j] = ' '
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Solved my problem.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen: you're welcome. You made a small typo on your profile page: it is *spare* time, not *spear* time :)